# IOS 7 nested SKScenes with Physik Simulation

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, game-physics

I would like to use simulated physics with nodes in nested SKScenes in my Spritekit Game for iOS7.
But it doesnt work like it should.
Adding the physicsbody to the object from the child scene after adding the child scene to the main scene dont throw an error but it doesnt seem to work correctly.
The phsics from the child scene doesnt work.
Is there a better way to separate the static world from the dynamic objects?

For example:
I have the first main Scene:

```
@interface MyScene : SKScene
  // ...
@end

@implementation MyScene
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {   
  // ... setup blabla

  // first object
  SKSpriteNode *obj1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"obj1"];
  obj1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:obj1.size.height / 2];
  // ... obj1.physicsBody setup with collisionBitMask
  [self addChild:obj1];


  // New SKScene with second Object
  World *world = [[World alloc] initWithSize:size];
  [self addChild:obj1];
  [world addObjects];
}
@end
```

and the World SKScene Class:

```
@interface World : SKScene
  // ...
@end


@implementation World

-(void)addObject{
  // second object
  SKSpriteNode *obj2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"obj2"];
  obj2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:obj2.size.height / 2];
  // ... obj2.physicsBody setup with collisionBitMask and dynamic = no
  [self addChild:obj2];

}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one scene running/active/presented at a time.

So the basic premise of having two scenes is futile. That physics isn't working (as expected) in this scenario is just a symptom.

While you can create scene objects and add them as child to another scene, this will not make them work like a scene but rather they're treated more like a regular SKNode. You should also notice that you won't receive contact callbacks in the sub-scene, nor will it receive `update`, `didEvaluateActions` and `didSimulatePhysics` messages.

Comment: Adding a `SKScene` as a child of another scene seems rather useless considering I cannot update a scene's position :/